# How to validate the uploaded file is valid certificate[Content of the certificate] in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am uploading certificates[.cert, .pem etc] to the backend. I want to validate the content format so that the file uploaded is valid certificate. What would be the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Run the snippet below. - Try it by uploading a file that isn't `cert` or `pem`

You can add additional file types here:

```
 if (fileInput.value.includes("cert") || fileInput.value.includes("pem"))
```

```js
var fileInput = document.getElementById("fileInput")

function checkInputType() {
//allow cert or pem file types
if (fileInput.value.includes("cert") || fileInput.value.includes("pem")){
alert("This file type is allowed")
}
else {
//alert if file type is not cert or pem
alert("File type is not allowed, please choose a valid file")
//remove invalid input value
fileInput.value = ""
}
}
```

```html
<input type="file" id="fileInput" onchange="checkInputType();"></input>
```

Comment: I want to validate the content of the certificate

Answer (score 0):

You can use a framework like https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge :

***index.html***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="forge.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="file" id="myfile" name="file" onchange="handleChange(event);"></input>
    <br>
    <p id="isValidKey"></p>
    <p id="isValidCertificate"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

***script.js***

```
function handleChange(event) {
    console.log(event)
    let fileContent = event.target.files[0]
    let fileReader = new FileReader()
    fileReader.onload = (e) => {
        let content = e.target.result
        let pki = forge.pki;
        let isValidCertificate = checkCertificate(content)
        let isValidKey = checkKey(content)
        console.log(content)
        output(isValidCertificate, isValidKey)
    }
    fileReader.readAsText(fileContent)
}

function checkCertificate(content) {
    let pki = forge.pki;
    let isValid = false
    try {
        let cert = pki.certificateFromPem(content);
        isValid = true
    } catch (e) {
        isValid = false
    }
    return isValid
}

function checkKey(content) {
    let pki = forge.pki;
    let isValid = false
    try {
        let privateKey = pki.encryptedPrivateKeyFromPem(content);
        isValid = true
    } catch (e) {
        isValid = false
    }
    return isValid
}

function output(isValidCertificate, isValidKey) {
    console.log('Private key is valid ', isValidKey)
    console.log('Certificate is valid ', isValidCertificate)
    document.getElementById('isValidKey').innerHTML = `Private key is valid: ${isValidKey}`
    document.getElementById('isValidCertificate').innerHTML = `Certificate is  valid: ${isValidCertificate}`
}
```

***package.json***

```
{
  "name": "validate_upload_file",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "forge-dist": "github:fabiorecife/forge-dist"
  }
}
```

you can change the dependencies to ***https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge-dist***

Comment: to get some value from the certificate just use for example: cert.subject